# equivalent /s /V"/qn in powershell command

Tags: powershell

I am trying to convert a silent installer command given for a application
this runs perfectly fine in ̣bat file but I need to run this in powershell for one of the autodeployment tasks

```
"BubblePop.exe" /s /V"/qn /lie Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit"
```

the error that I get is

> You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.
>   at line 1 character 17 at /s

I tried the following -

Adding it under a variable:

```
$command = "BubblePop.exe" /s /V"/qn Target=C:\Users\amit 
TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit" 
Invoke Expression $command
```

adding @ :

```
@'"BubblePop.exe" /s /V"/qn Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit"'@
```

I think the issue is with `/s` but not been able to get a workaround.
This command works in windows cmd prompt. Is there a way to get a workaround?

Comment: `Start-Process -FilePath <FullpathToBubblePop.exe> -Argumentlist "/s","/V","/qn","Target=C:\Users\amit","TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit" ` ?

Comment: @Paxz That's not the same thing.  The double-quote is part of the command.

Comment: @Paxz: `Start-Process` is generally not an alternative to direct invocation, because it works fundamentally differently (asynchronously, no integration with PowerShell's output streams).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/s` is a red herring, as it is just a follow-on error from your fundamental problem:

**You cannot *directly* invoke a file name or path that is *single- or double-quoted*; instead,  you must use `&`, the call operator**:

```
& "BubblePop.exe" /s /V"/qn /lie Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit"
```

Of course, with an executable name such as `BubblePop.exe`, which has no embedded spaces, single- or double-quoting it isn't strictly needed and can simply be omitted, in which case the use of `&` is optional:

```
BubblePop.exe /s /V"/qn /lie Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit"
```

Additionally, note that the double quotes around the value following `/V` will *not* be preserved when the whole argument is passed to `BubblePop.exe`, because PowerShell transforms the whole argument to
`"/V/qn /lie Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit"`
, i.e., puts double quotes around the *whole* argument, so that `BubblePop.exe` ultimately sees the argument as
`/V/qn /lie Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit`
If `BubblePop.exe` does need these double quotes, however, you must *escape* them as `` `" `` in order to pass them through:

```
& "BubblePop.exe" /s /V`"/qn /lie Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit`"
```

<sup>On a side note: This wouldn't work in PowerShell *Core* on *Unix*-like platforms, where even the escaped `"` instances would be stripped.</sup>

---

**If you start a statement with `'` or a `"`, PowerShell parses it in *expression* mode (like a programming language) rather than *argument* mode (like a shell)** - see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

E.g., `"BubblePop.exe"` by itself would simply be interpreted as an (expandable) *string* literal that by default is simply *output* to the console.

When `"BubblePop.exe" /s ...` is parsed, `/` is interpreted as the *division operator*, which obviously expects a *number* after it (the divisor); and an unexpected token such as `s` causes the `You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator.` error you saw.

Comment: Will the double quote on the verbose switch be parsed correctly?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: Good question: please see my update.

Comment: @mkelement0 thank you for the solution and the explanation. It worked like a charm :) :)

Comment: @nova_rubo: My pleasure; glad to hear it was helpful.

Comment: @mklement0: just another small query on this. Would the query vary when you are executing this command via a remote execution?? we see arguments after (`) parameter is not getting through when we trigger this command from another machine.

Comment: @nova_rubo: No, generally I would expect the syntax to be the same, but how exactly are you invoking the command remotely? Please create a _new question_ for this; feel free to ping me here once you have done so.

Answer (score 0):

You need to quote your arguments or they'll be interpreted as operators by the powershell parser.  You have that option, or the stop parser operator (`--%`) which will fall back to the `cmd` parser in v3+:

```
BubblePop.exe '/s' '/V"/qn Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit"'
```

or

```
BubblePop.exe --% /s /V"/qn Target=C:\Users\amit TARGETDIR=C:\Users\amit"
```

Comment: No, in _argument mode_ tokens such as `/s` are _not_ interpreted as operators, only in _expression mode_. By omitting the `"..."` around `BubblePop.exe` you've implicitly switched to argument mode, in which case something like `/s` works both with and without quoting. The OP's problem was simply the use of `"..."` around `BubblePop.exe` (without being preceded by `&`), which caused the entire statement to be parsed in expression mode.

Comment: @mklement0 y'know, I use this tool every day and still feel like I don't know anything at times. Thanks for the correction